# Как сделать массив, содержащий только картинки?

Tags: javascript, angular2

какими способами можно сделать массив только из картинок?

```
"reviews": [
  {
    "id": 32641,
    "text": "отлично",
    "authorName": "Lena",
    "staffName": "Марина",
    "pictures": [
      {
        "url": "/static/img/picture-missing/review_picture.jpg?v=1"
      },
      {
        "url": "/static/img/picture-missing/review_picture.jpg?v=1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 25638,
    "text": "так себе мастер",
    "authorName": "Sasha",
    "staffName": "Марина",
    "pictures": [
      {
        "url": "/static/img/picture-missing/review_picture.jpg?v=1"
      },
      {
        "url": "/static/img/picture-missing/review_picture.jpg?v=1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
нужен такой массив, для его передачи другому компоненту, который при клике увеличивает картинки.
[
"url": "/static/img/picture-missing/review_picture.jpg?v=1", 
"url": "/static/img/picture-missing/review_picture.jpg?v=1",
"url": "/static/img/picture-missing/review_picture.jpg?v=1",
"url": "/static/img/picture-missing/review_picture.jpg?v=1"
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const data = { "reviews": [
  {
    "id": 32641,
    "text": "отлично",
    "authorName": "Lena",
    "staffName": "Марина",
    "pictures": [
      {
        "url": "/static/img/picture-missing/review_picture.jpg?v=1"
      },
      {
        "url": "/static/img/picture-missing/review_picture.jpg?v=1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 25638,
    "text": "так себе мастер",
    "authorName": "Sasha",
    "staffName": "Марина",
    "pictures": [
      {
        "url": "/static/img/picture-missing/review_picture.jpg?v=1"
      },
      {
        "url": "/static/img/picture-missing/review_picture.jpg?v=1"
      }
    ]
  }
]}

const result = data.reviews.flatMap(review=>review.pictures)
console.log(result)
console.log(result.map(pic=>pic.url))
```

Comment: Спасибо @Sergei Kirjanov, сильно помогли

Comment: Сергей, подскажите, как сделать массив картинок каждого мастера?

Comment: @the cop, пример?

Comment: user Lena загрузила 2 картинки мастеру Марина user Sasha загрузила тоже 2 картинки мастеру Марина, как сделать, чтобы в массив кидал 2 картинки от Lena? @Sergei Kirjanov

Comment: Ничего не понял ... какаие структуры на входе, и какие на выходе?

Comment: на входе тот же объект, который указан в const data, на выходе массив картинок каждого мастера

Comment: Если массив массивов, то `map` вместо `flatMap`. Если одного из -- `......review.staffName==="Марина"?review.pictures:[])`

Comment: Спасибо Сергей 